# Dirac delta in Fourier space for finite volume

Tags: dirac-delta-distributions, discrete, volume, lattice-model

In some class notes about cosmology I have found the following claim. The author starts by stating that the Dirac delta is given by:

$$\delta^{(D)}(\vec{x}+\vec{x}')=\int\dfrac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i(\vec{x}+\vec{x}')\cdot\vec{q}}$$

and then continues by saying that, in particular, for finite volumes this leads to:

$$\delta^{(D)}(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')=\dfrac{V}{(2\pi)^3}\delta_{\vec{k},\vec{k}'}^{(K)}.$$

I know how to obtain the first formula, by computing the Fourier transform of the Dirac delta, then applying the inverse transform and using the parity of the delta function. However, I'm lost as to what to do to prove the second one for finite volumes. I have no idea of how to make the Kronecker delta appear in the result. I have attempted to compute the Fourier transform of the first expression but that doesn't seem to take me anywhere.

On a side note, it seems strange to me that he denotes the wavenumber $k$ as $q$ in the first formula, something that is not consistent with the rest of the notes, and I wonder if it means something.

Any suggestions on how to proceed to obtain this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the second equation, there is an (implicit) limit $V\to \infty$ hidden on the RHS. To see this, start e.g. from $f(k)=\sum\limits_{k^\prime} \delta_{kk^\prime} f(k^\prime)$ and take the thermodynamic limit.

Comment: @TobiasFünke How? I am completely lost on how to proceed. It must be really simple but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Alternatively, take the limit $L\to \infty$ of the equation $\int\limits_{-L/2}^{L/2} \mathrm dx\, e^{i(k-k^\prime)x} = L\delta_{k,k^\prime}$, where $k=\frac{2\pi}{L} n$ for some $n\in \mathbb Z$. The LHS yields a common representation of the Dirac delta (up to a factor of $2\pi$) and thus the desired result follows.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I don't understand why your first equation is true. If I integrate the left hand side I get $2\sin[(k-k')L/2]$. Am I making some dumb mistake here?

Comment: Just plug in the values for $k$... and note that your result only holds for $k\neq k^\prime$. For $k=k^\prime$, the integration yields...?

Comment: @TobiasFünke Oh! So, if I plug in the values for $k=(2\pi/L)n$ and $k=(2\pi/L)n'$, what I get is that the LHS equals $2\sin(n-n')\pi$, which is always zero since $n-n'$ is an integer. So, indeed the result is zero if $k\neq k'$. And if $k=k'$ the LHS integral is $L$. Thank you so much!